# Program runs but nothing displays

Tags: java

I have been trying to get my character to move in the game I am trying to program for a while now. I managed to get it to display but when I added the code that was supposed to move it it doesn't display any more. I'm new to coding so I've been basing mine off of some code I found online with a few slight changes and I don't know what I did wrong.

Execute.java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Execute extends JFrame {
 public Execute() {
  initUI();
 }

 public static void initUI() {
  JFrame jf = new JFrame();
  jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  jf.setSize(600,600);
  jf.setTitle("I am the salad baby");

  jf.add(new Board());
 }

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    Execute ex = new Execute();
    ex.setVisible(true);
   }
  });
 }
}
```

Craft.java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Craft {
 private int dx;
 private int dy;
 private int x;
 private int y;
 private BufferedImage image;

 public Craft() {
  initCraft();
 }

 private void initCraft() {
  Painter painter = new Painter();
  BufferedImage image = painter.createBufImg("Images/SpriteSheet.png");
  x = 40;
  y = 60;
 }

 public void move() {
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
 }

 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }

 public int getY() {
  return y;
 }

 public BufferedImage getImage() {
  return image;
 }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  int key = e.getKeyCode();

  if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
   dx = -1;
  }

  if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
   dx = 1;
  }

  if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
   dy = -1;
  }

  if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
   dy = 1;
  }
 }

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   int key = e.getKeyCode();

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    dx = 0;
   }

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
    dx = 0;
   }

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    dy = 0;
   }

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
   dy = 0;
  }
 }
}
```

Board.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 private Timer timer;
 private Craft craft;
 private final int DELAY = 10;

 public Board() {
  initBoard();
 }

 private void initBoard() {
  addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
  setFocusable(true);

  craft = new Craft();

  timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
  timer.start();
 }

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  doDrawing(g);
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
 }

 private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2d.drawImage(craft.getImage(), craft.getX(), craft.getY(), this);
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  craft.move();
  repaint();
 }

 private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   craft.keyReleased(e);
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   craft.keyPressed(e);
  }
 }
}
```

Painter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Painter extends JPanel {
 BufferedImage createBufImg(String filepath) {
  try {
   return ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Could not read image");
  }
  return null;
 }
}
```

Any input is helpful!

Comment: It looks like you're only painting when an ActionEvent is fired. I've never used it personally, but I'm not entirely sure if it fires for keypresses. Are you certain that the function `actionPerformed` is being called?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Execute extends JFrame {
 public Execute() {
  initUI();
 }

 public void initUI() {
  // you were creating an entirely different frame here
  // instead initialize **this** frame
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setSize(600,600);
  setTitle("I am the salad baby");

  add(new Board());
 }
// ...
}
```

Comment: @user4052054 The explanation is inside the fragment in comments. Execute is a class extending JFrame, ie it is a frame. It is also the frame you want to be showing. In your initUI method you were initializing another frame you created by `new JFrame()`. All I did is make initUI a member variable that initializes the frame you want to be initializing, ie the Execute frame.

Comment: @user4052054 Oh, sorry, I just didn't see it.

Comment: @user4052054 No worries... I meant to say *make initUI a member method* of course :)

Comment: Thanks, but the sprite still doesn't display.

Comment: @CharlieLandrigan You're welcome, that was apparantly just one of several problems.  When posting questions like these, it's best to post an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) (short self-contained example). It's not easy debugging code from eye-balling several snippets stitched together.

Comment: Okay, how do I write one of those?

Comment: @CharlieLandrigan I thought the link explained it pretty well. Basically write everything in a single class, stripping anything that is irrelevant to the problem. Then if people want to help, they can copy/paste in their IDE and debug your program. With several individual snippets that is no longer possible or practical and you can't expect people here to do that.